# How to Prove that the set $M$ is Homeomorphic to $\mathbb{R}$?

Tags: general-topology

This question was in general topology, but I couldn't find a technique to solve it.

We let the set $M$ :   $M=\{(x,y)\in \mathbb{R}^2 ; 4x^3+27y^2=0 \}$

Is there a technique to prove that the set $M$ is homeomorphic to $\mathbb{R}$ ?

Comment: Consider the map $y\mapsto((-27y^2/4)^{1/3},y).$

Comment: Think of $M$ like you twist the negative $x$-axis and the positive one and move it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$4x^3 +27y^2 = 0$ iff $x = (\frac{-27y^2}{4})^{\frac{1}{3}}$.
So the map $$t \mapsto ((\frac{-27t^2}{4})^{\frac{1}{3}}, t) 
$$ is going to be a homeomorphism from $\mathbb{R}$ to M.

Intuitively, if you graph M on a grid, it will be a simple endless curve on the plane, therefore making it homeomorphic to the real line.

Comment: Thank you Mr. @Pedro Lourenço Thanks for help.